# facebook page conversation webhook get message content

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I get a conversation webhook when there is a new message on a page (conversation changes webhook), but how do i get that message content? Below is what the webhook looks like:

```
{"entry":[{"changes":[{"field":"conversations","value":{"thread_id":"t_mid.1467550763532:90df1b42684fd25a61","page_id":2959874586841}}],"id":"2959054086841","time":1467156268}],"object":"page"}
```

and then I can do make a graph api request (with page token) to:

> t_mid.1467150763538:90df162684fd25a69/messages

and i get:

```
    {"data": [{"created_time": "2016-06-29T00:24:42+0000", "id": "m_mid.14671598826:009a97e7037f33c693"}, {"created_time": "2016-06-28T23:24:27+0000", "id": "m_mid.14671562658:cf5f62913d39905671"}, .... ], "paging": {"previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/t_mid.1467150763538:90df62684fd25a69/messages?format=json&access_token=EAATq772LHHQBZAXXX&limit=25&since=1467159882&__paging_token=enc_AdXXX&__previous=1", "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/t_mid.14671507538:90df1b6268d25a69/messages?format=json&access_token=ETXXX&limit=25&until=1467150763&__paging_token=enc_AXXX"} }
```

My question is: how do i get the message content of the recent webhook? Do i have to go through each of these messages one at a time and see if I have already saved them in my database or not? Seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: you have found any solution, I have same problem. Please add answer if you have got any!

Answer (score 0):

use the thread_Id to get the contents 
e.g:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/<threadId>?fields=messages{message,created_time,from,to},scoped_thread_key,updated_time&access_token=<PAGEACCESSTOKEN>
```